# How can I read a text file from the terminal and save the output to another file in java?

Tags: java

Hey all I'm fairly new to this but I want to not hardcode a file to be read in but I want to read it in from the terminal/command prompt. Here is what I have so far, I'm hardcoding the filename in bufferedWriter but how can I make it to where I can do a command such as (java main < in.txt > out.txt). Thanks in advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String inFile = "in.txt";
    String outFile = "out.txt";

    if (args.length > 1) {
        inFile = args[0];
        outFile = args[1];
    }

    Lexer lexer = new Lexer(inFile);

    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));

        Token t;

        while ((t = lexer.nextToken()) != null) {
            writer.write(t.toString());
            writer.newLine();
        }

        writer.close(); 

        System.out.println("Done tokenizing file: " + inFile);
        System.out.println("Output written in file: " + outFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*You* don't, the OS handles the IO redirection with `java main < in.txt > out.txt`. Instead you read from `System.in` and write to `System.out`. *Alternatively*, based on the code you posted you might run it with

```
java main in.txt out.txt
```

Then your program would receive `"in.txt"` as `args[0]` and `"out.txt"` as `args[1]`.

Comment: So why can't i use the "<" or ">"? Isn't that how you tell your program to read in the file and output the results in the other file? Also when I put in System.in or System.out it gives me a error saying its not applicable.

Comment: @Rod When you use the ``<`` or ``>`` the *Operating System* redirects the [Standard Streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#1995:_Java) stdin and stdout (e.g. `System.in` and `System.out` in Java).

Comment: Ok, So what can I change in my code to allow me to use System.in and System.out? I'm trying different things but I either get an error or I get stuck trying.

Comment: If you are on a UNIX system, you could use "/dev/stdin" and "/dev/stdout". If not, I think you'll have to modify your code to work with streams instead of files.

Comment: Yes I am on a UNIX system

Comment: @Rod It should work then if you change to `String inFile = "/dev/stdin";` and `String outFile = "/dev/stdout";`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! It works using that method. I can't express how much time you saved me. Thank you very much again

Answer (score 0):

Read from `System.in` and write to `System.out` - also remember anything you write to `System.out` will be written to the file. such as `Done tokenizing file: + inFile`